# Do solutions over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ tell me anything about solutions over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, finite-fields

Yo, this is probably some nonsense stupid question, but I will ask it anyway.

Let $X$ be some variety over $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that I know $X (\mathbb{F}_{p^n})$ for every $n$. Does it tell me anything about $X (\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

The motivation is kind of idiot. A solution of a system of polynomial equations over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the same thing as a solution modulo $p^n$ for every $n$, so the collection of all $X (\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$ tell me exactly $X (\mathbb{Q}_p)$. So first order approximations of solutions over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are exactly $X (\mathbb{F}_p)$.

More generally, what can be said for arbitrary global fields instead of simply $\mathbb{Q}$? I care mainly about number fields, but an answer about functional fields only would also be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Z_p is the inverse limit of Z/p^n. Z/p^n is not a field if (n > 1) Where as F_p^n is a field. Q is a global field Q_p is a local field. I am not sure how your last paragraph relates to the rest of the question.

Comment: @DBS I mean the analogous question for arbitrary completions of global fields at any nonarchimedean place.

Comment: I think this question needs a little bit more specificity to be really good. What are you after in particular? Typically, when one talks of points over $\Bbb F_q$ or $\Bbb Z/p^n$, one looks at the point counts and reasons from there. Are you attempting to verify certain properties of $X(\Bbb Q_p)$ from the point counts? The missing idea from the post seems to be how you're hoping to use the points.

Comment: @KReiser I agree that the question lacks motivation and it's completely vague. I was initially trying to see if under the assumption that $X (\mathbb{F}_{p^n})$ is non-empty for every $n$ plus some global-local property, it would be possible to decide whether $X (\mathbb{Q})$ was empty or not (say $X$ is something like a Brauer-Severi variety or some quadric). I know it still vague.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the behaviors of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ and $\Bbb Z/p^n$ as $n\to\infty$ are two very different things. Taking $n\to\infty$ on the field side is done by taking a colimit, and gets you to $\overline{\Bbb F}_{p}$, the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$. On the $\Bbb Z/p^n$ side, taking $n\to \infty$ happens via a limit, and the result is the $p$-adics.

For example, if one takes the variety given by $x^2+1=0$ where $p=3$, this variety won't have any points over $\Bbb Q_3$ or any ring of the form $\Bbb Z/3^n$, but it has points over $\Bbb F_{3^{2n}}$ for all $n$.

In general, determining the behavior of solutions over $\Bbb Q_p$ given the behavior over $\Bbb Z/p^n$ is a problem solved by Hensel's lemma, while there's generally not a relationship between the behavior of solutions over $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ and $\Bbb Q_p$. Hensel's lemma and concepts in $p$-adic analysis are where I think you might do well to poke around while developing the ideas contained in your question. If you're interested in comparing results modulo every prime and over $\Bbb Q$, you might want to look up the Hasse principle and counterexamples to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $X (\mathbb{F}_{p^n})$  gives first order approximations (by Hensel lemma) of solutions $X(K_n)$ for $K_n$ extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with residue $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. So I was expecting that this data would be of some use. But your simple counter-example shows that this data is likely useless.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a bit confusing in that you're comparing the colimit of the $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ to the limit of the $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$

Comment: Added some clarification of limit vs. colimit.